# C++ Container of Non-Interleaved Stored Tuples

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures, containers, memory-alignment

I'm looking for a variant of `std::vector` or `std::array` of **tuples**, where the tuple elements are placed ***non-interleaved*** into separate memory areas instead of interleaved as would be the case for, for example, a `std::vector<std::tuple<...>>`.

The motivations for this is

- Better ***control*** over ***alignment*** and in turn better performance for vector optimizations.
- Prevents us from having to ***unpack*** data-elements when interfacing low-level CPU-GPU data-transfer-operations (such as an array of vertices and colors) in OpenGL.

Iterators should construct and return a `boost::tuple<>` ***on-the-fly*** when dereferenced.

I'm aware that not all STL-member functions could be supported efficiently in this container. For example the STL `data()` container member function would have to ***dynamically zip*** together all the separate arrays into a mutable dynamically created vector container and return its data().

Has anybody constructed such a table container already?

Comment: Wouldn't it be really simple to create one of these by writing a UDT that composes _n_ `std::vectors`, and provides the necessary interface? Of course, retrieval would _always_ involve a copy, which is a bit ugly.

Comment: @Tomalak: I think retrieval could return a tuple of references, avoiding copying.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Oh, maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) has exactly what you describe: [`boost::zip_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html)

Comment: Ok, that solves the iterator stuff! Great! However, we still need a tuple-templatized table-like container that keeps track of the arrays preferrably with only one instance of `size` and `room` data members. If we are lazy we could include a set of `std::vector` but that wastes some space for small instances. Ok. lets be lazy! We could start with writing an UDT that composes _n_ `std::vectors` as mentioned above. Is a `table` a good name for such a container?

Comment: @Nordlöw : Sorry, I don't have any particular insight on that. Is a `tuple<vector1<A>, vector2<B>, ..., vectorN<N>>` not sufficient, or do you just want a nice way of encapsulating something like that?

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a thin wrapper that supports iteration and a few other operations around a `tuple<vector, vector, vector>` and representing the data in that way? I'm not aware of any standard container that provides the interface you need.